# Shortlists and job offers

Tags: mathjobs, career

I hope this question is appropriate for MO. I started application process this year. I've searched several online ads for a job and found a wiki page, which contains names of people that have been shortlisted. I've got listed in couple places as well and I wonder if this can harm my application process. I would like to know pros and cons of this open source.

Comment: Good question, though I believe you receive better answers at http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Andras, the web site that you mention is more PhD student related. There are no sources on tenure track positions there. I think the audience here is more familiar with the question that I am asking.

Comment: In view of your comment to Andreas Blass's answer perhaps it could make sense to clarify/make more explcit your question. Note that you can edit the question (button just below the text of the question).   

Comment: I think this is way off topic for MO. I will refrain from voting to close as I can see from this and other examples that there is an incredible pent-up demand for this kind of discussion which doesn't seem to have other outlets. I wish the AMS or a similar organization showed some leadership to create a forum for discussions about the profession. Is there any AMS officer among MO users?

Comment: I opened a discussion on meta based on my comment in case anyone wants to reply to it. http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1509/questions-about-the-profession/

Comment: Contrary to what you say in your comment above, Academia StackExchange has questions about tenure track positions.  Look, for example, at http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=tenure+track+position

Comment: The question received a thoughtful answer and some quick general feed-back regarding the matter. A longer *discussion* regarding the merits of the existence of "rumor mills" (for academic jobs) and the respective merits of cooperating with them, seems clearly not on topic for MO, even more so as this doesn't seem like a question very specific to the *math* job-market. For further pursuing this matter (in case there is interested by OP or anybody) the suggested alternative site  seems well-suited. Contributing a vote to close. (In case anybody reasks there, perhaps add a link here.)

Comment: For general information: a variant of this question got (re)asked on academia.SE http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6021/rumor-mill-and-math-job

Answer (score 14):

I would think that having it known that you're short-listed at some places would help rather than harm your chances at other places.  If some department ignored your application because they failed to notice anything special and it was one among $N$ (and $N\to\infty$), knowing that you're on some other place's short list might cause them to take another look.  You're probably worried that some departments will assume that you'll get an offer from better places, with which they can't compete, so they won't seriously consider you.  I doubt that this would be a real problem; hiring committees are well aware that there's a difference between being on a short list and actually getting an offer.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas, for the reply. I am worried also about the fact that several names appeared to be much more shortlisted then others. this can be a consequence of wiki web site, which increases their popularity dramatically. So in some cases (like mine) it is better not to appear on the list (I have only two interviews). Basically, I wonder how harmful or useful this site can be in general.

Comment: Dear Fanny S: As someone on the hiring end (for some years now), if it's any tiny comfort I have never heard anyone say on a hiring committee "This person is on the rumor mill, let's (re)consider them" (or even bring up the rumor mill at all in the context of such decisions); i.e., decisions are based on the content of the application (rec. letters, research statement, etc.) and not unprofessional things like following a herd based on a wiki rumor mill.  With all due respect to Greg K., personally I think the negative aspects to the wiki rumor mill far outweigh the positive ones.

Comment: kreck, I think I share your opinion. Also could you please expand what negative aspects do you have in mind. Thanks

Comment: Dear Fanny S: My opinions are based on imagining how mortified I would have been if this existed when I was at your stage. Here are some negatives I see. (1) The rumor mill (if accurate...) reveals who gets no offer and who does poorly on shortlists, which is nobody else's business but the person's own, (2) it reveals where one gets various offers, but maybe the candidate prefers such information to be revealed only at their own discretion (for multiple reasons), (3) it reveals the order in which a department goes down the shortlist, hurting various relations, (4) it can spread *false* rumors.

Comment: By the way, I recognize that my objection #4 is also a bug of rumors spreading the old-fashioned way, but in the classical setting the spread is much less than when posted for the "whole world" to see on the Internet. Loss of control over one's privacy makes me glad that the Internet did not exist when I was growing up. In various ways I think that growing up in the age of Facebook (so to speak) must be really unpleasant for a lot of kids, and the objections I have to the rumor mill are in the same spirit as those concerns. But enough of this non-mathematical chatter, sorry.

Comment: I wonder who publishes short lists of applicants. My department certainly does not, neither before nor after positions are filled. And, of course I cannot speak for our lawyers, but I cannot imagine them embracing the idea.

Comment: @Michael Renardy : For the most part, I believe that the shortlists are posted by people who carefully scan the seminar/colloquium schedules of departments to try to figure out the shortlist.  However, I can confirm that at one place I interviewed at several years ago, the department chair told me that he had posted the shortlist to the wiki.  It seemed pretty weird to me.  Certainly at my own department people are aware of the wiki, but pretty much ignore it.

Comment: I agree with Kreck's reasons for being unhappy with the posting of short lists. Nevertheless, I still feel that being on the short lists of some schools is more likely to help than to hurt on's chances elsewhere. If Andy Putnam is right that the posted short lists are often inferred from seminar and colloquium schedules, then I'd expect them to be full of errors. 